# Installing Ruby/Rubygems error @ Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, yaml

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu following the steps from "[How to Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) with RVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)".

Everything worked well until here:

```
gabi@ubuntu:~$ rvm rubygems current
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.25 for ruby-1.9.3-p385 ...
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/home/gabi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385:/home/gabi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global:/home/gabi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385:/home/gabi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global GEM_HOME=/home/gabi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385 /home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/setup.rb', please read /home/gabi/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
```

The log file looks like this:

```
/home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:36:in `remove_method': method `to_yaml' not defined in Object (Nam
eError)
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:36:in `yamler='
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:33:in `class_eval'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:33:in `yamler='
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:76:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems.rb:680:in `load_yaml'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:249:in `load_file'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:190:in `initialize'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
  from /home/gabi/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.25/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
  from setup.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

What's exactly the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: I think it's safe to skip the step. I don't recall ever doing that. Check on the official rvm site.

Comment: i tried to skip it but when i'm trying to install rails i get the same output like the one in the log file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what was the problem, I think something went wrong on installing, however I managed to make it work by using the quick fix from [here](https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/):

1. Update RVM using: `rvm get head`
2. Remove all the manually installed packages using: `rvm pkg remove`
3. Install the required libraries using: `rvm requirements run`
4. Reinstall Ruby using: `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could think of is if you're using the wrong Ruby version.  If you're using `rm`, type `rvm current` and see if it's Ruby 1.9.