# RVM error installing rubygems on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I have an ubuntu machine and I am trying to install rubygems using RVM by following this guide:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

When I run the command `rvm rubygems current` or even the command `rvm rubygems latest` I get the following error:

```
fl4m3ph03n1x: ~ $ rvm rubygems current
system - #downloading rubygems-2.4.8
system - #extracting rubygems-2.4.8.....
system - #removing old rubygems.........
$LANG was empty, setting up LANG=en_US.utf8, if it fails again try setting LANG to something sane and try again.
system - #installing rubygems-2.4.8.
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/gems/system@global GEM_PATH= /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby -d /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.8/setup.rb --no-document',
showing last 15 lines of /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/log/1437602750_system/rubygems.install.log
[2015-07-22 22:05:50] /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby
current path: /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/bin
command(7): env GEM_HOME=/home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/gems/system@global GEM_PATH= /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby -d /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.8/setup.rb --no-document
env: /home/fl4m3ph03n1x/.rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

At first I thought the error was due to the `--no-document` flag, but after reading and trying [this discussion on github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3152), nothing changed.

I also checked this [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969019/installing-ruby-rubygems-error-ubuntu) but it doesn't seem to be applicable to my case because I have a fresh installation (no manually installed packages nor anything).

Over all I tried using commands like `rvm get head` and `rvm stable` but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing? Could this be a permission's problem somehow?

**EDIT:**

This is the result of `rvm list`:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: it seems you do not have ruby instaled, what rvm list shows?

Comment: edited the question to have your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had ruby installed, but turns out it was not set in rvm. 
To fix this first I tried using `rvm use ruby --default`, but I got the infamous "rvm is not a function" error.

To fix this, first run `bash --login` and then then `rvm use ruby --default`.

Once these steps are complete you can proceed with rubygems installation.